# How to calculate the entropy in the ID3 decision tree algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-trees, id3-algorithm, entropy

Here is the definition of the entropy

$$H(S)=-\sum_{x \in X} p(x) \log _{2} p(x)$$

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm#Entropy)'s description of entropy breaks down the formula, but I still don't know how to determine the values of $X$, defined as

> The set of classes in $S$

and $p(x)$, defined as

> The proportion of the number of elements in class $x$ to the number of elements in set $S$.

Can anyone break this down further to explain how to find $p(x)$?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have data:

```
color  height  quality
=====  ======  =======
green  tall    good
green  short   bad
blue   tall    bad
blue   short   medium
red    tall    medium
red    short   medium
```

To calculate the entropy for quality in this example:

```
X  = {good, medium, bad}
x1 = {good}, x2 = {bad}, x3 = {medium}
```

Probability of each x in X:

```
p1 = 1/6 = 0.16667
p2 = 2/6 = 0.33333
p3 = 3/6 = 0.5
```

for which logarithms are:

```
log2(p1) = -2.58496
log2(p2) = -1.58496
log2(p3) = -1.0
```

and therefore entropy for the set is:

```
H(X) = - (0.16667 * -2.58496) - (0.33333 * -1.58496) - (0.5 * -1.0)
     = 1.45915
```

by the formula in the question.

Remaining tasks are to iterate this process for each attribute to form the nodes of the tree.

Comment: how are p1, p2, and p3 calculated?

Comment: `p1 = 1/6 = 0.16667`
`p2 = 2/6 = 0.33333`
`p3 = 3/6 = 0.5`

Answer (score 0):

Very nice example that makes perfect sense to me. To get the value into expected range [0..1] [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Efficiency_(normalized_entropy)) is needed.

$H(S)_{norm}=\frac{H(S)}{log_2(|S|)}=\frac{H( \{good, bad, bad, medium, medium, medium\} )}{log_2(3)}=\frac{1.459147917027245}{1.584962500721156}=0.9206198357143052 \in [0..1]$

✔️